# How can I know the PID of the other end of a perl IO::Pipe

Tags: perl, process, pipe, pid

I have setup another process that I watch for output, using IO::Pipe

```
my $pipe  = IO::Pipe->new();
my $fh    = $pipe->reader( $dirWatcher );
```

I then setup a IO::Select to watch $fh.

That all works fine, however sometimes I would like to kill the $dirWatcher process.

My first thought was to save the PID when I create the reader, and then just call kill when I needed.

However, IO::Pipe does not seem to provide a way for me to know the PID.

So do I have to duplicate the function of IO::Pipe::reader? Is there an simple way I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reader` and `writer` methods of IO::Pipe return instances of IO::Pipe::End. This class specializes IO::Handle with a `close` method.

```
sub close {
    my $fh = shift;
    my $r = $fh->SUPER::close(@_);

    waitpid(${*$fh}{'io_pipe_pid'},0)
        if(defined ${*$fh}{'io_pipe_pid'});

    $r;
}
```

The process ID is there but not exposed in the public interface. This appears to be a gap.

You can get at the pid as in the following program.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Pipe;

my $pipe = IO::Pipe->new;
my $fh = $pipe->reader("sleep 5; echo hi");

my $pid = ${*$pipe}{'io_pipe_pid'};
system "ps", "ww", $pid;

print while <$fh>;
```

Output:

```
$ ./get-reader-pid
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 3500 pts/0    S+     0:00 sh -c sleep 5; echo hi
[5-second wait]
hi
```

As the [perlmodlib](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib.html#NOTE) documentation indicates, poking into objects’ internals isn’t a grievous sin. Understand the risks, however.

> Perl does not enforce private and public parts of its modules as you may have been used to in other languages like C++, Ada, or Modula-17.  Perl doesn't have an infatuation with enforced privacy. It would prefer that you stayed out of its living room because you weren't invited, not because it has a shotgun.

You may feel a bit dirty about doing this, and you should. It is not part of the public interface and is therefore subject to change without notice. In practical terms, the likelihood of change is low, and even if it does happen, you will be able to adapt easily.

Answer (score 0):

From **perldoc IO::Pipe**

```
           use IO::Pipe;

           $pipe = new IO::Pipe;

           if($pid = fork()) { # Parent
               $pipe->reader();

               while(<$pipe>) {
                   ...
               }

           }
           elsif(defined $pid) { # Child
               $pipe->writer();

               print $pipe ...
           }
```

Comment: I did try to use such a structure, but was unable to get a clean solution without zombies.